# Гистограмма повторяющихся элементов массива

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка, вывод, гистограммы

Дан массив из  чисел 0, 1, . . ., −1.
Постройте гистограмму значений элементов массива: для каждого значения подсчитайте
сколько раз оно встречается в массиве.
В первой строке записано целое число  (1 <=  <= 10^5).
Во второй строке через пробел записано  целых чисел  (1 <=  <= 10^4).
**Для каждого значения, которое встречается в массиве хотя бы раз, выведите сколько раз
оно присутствует среди элементов массива в формате: “значение: количество”.**
Значения требуется выводить в порядке возрастания.
Для вывода двух целых чисел, разделённых двоеточием с пробелом, удобно использовать
функцию printf со следующей форматной строкой:
`printf ("%d: %d", value , count );`
Программу делаю несколько дней; на выходе все элементы повторяются:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int N, kol;
    kol=1;
    int a[100000];
    scanf("%d\n", &N);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<N; i++){
        if (a[i]==a[i-1]){
            kol++;
        }
    printf("%d: %d\n", a[i], kol);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, что тут можно сделать/подправить, умоляю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int N;
    int a[10001] = {0};
    scanf("%d\n", &N);
    for(int i=0, x; i<N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        a[x]++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i < 10001; i++)
        if (a[i])  printf("%d: %d\n", i, a[i]);
}
```